# DynamoDB fast search on complex data types

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I need to create a new table on AWS DynamoDB that will have a structure like the following:

```
{
    "email" : String (key),
    ... : ...,
    "someStuff" : SomeType,
    ... : ...,

    "listOfIDs" : Array<String>    
}
```

This table contains users' data and a list of strings that I'll often query (see `listOfIDs`).
Since I don't want to `scan` the table every time in order to get the user linked to that specific ID due to its slowness, and I cannot create an index since it's an Array and not a "simple" type, how could I improve the structure of my table? Should I use a different table where I have all my IDs and the users linked to them in a "flat" structure? Is there any other way?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps another table that looks like:

```
ID    string / hash key,
Email string / range key,
Any other attributes you may want to access
```

The unique combination of `ID` and `email` will allow you to search on the "List of IDs". You may want to include other attributes within this table to save you from needing to perform another query.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use a different table where I have all my IDs and the users linked to them in a "flat" structure?

I think this is going to be your best bet if you want to leverage DynamoDB's parallelism for query performance.

Another option might be using a [`CONTAINS`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html) expression in a `query` if your `listOfIDs` is stored as a *set*, but I can't imagine that will scale performance-wise as your table grows.